# Create or edit Kubernetes secret from a job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-jobs

I am trying to generate a Kubernetes secret from a Kubernetes job. The secret is a TLS certificate, for elasticsearch transport, I tried this job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: conso-security-tls-gen-certs
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: generator
        volumeMounts:
          - name: certs
            mountPath: "/certs"
        image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.2"
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
        - "bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca (...) --silent -out /certs/bundle.p12"
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - name: certs
        secret:
          secretName: conso-security-tls-certs
  backoffLimit: 4
```

But as https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099 said, the volume `/certs` is ReadOnly. Is there a way to create/edit this secret like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Volumes from secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#secret) are gone once the container/pod is gone. Also, updating files in volumes created from a Secret will not update the Secret itself.

It seems that what the goal is from the Job to generate a cert and create or update a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) object with that cert? If that is the case I'd suggest looking into using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#secret-v1-core) or [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands) to manipulate Secrets from within the running container. You'd need to set up and use a [Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) that has permission to work with Secrets in the given namespace.

Comment: Thanks you, I was thinking this is a very common case (generate cert via a Job, and store inside a secret).

Comment: Usually, I think, Secrets are created in advance and referenced from environment variables or mounted as volumes. But I can also see how in a dynamic environment one may want to generate Secrets on the fly using Kubernetes Jobs.